# I use Inteliji , and i deleted a version of external library by mistake , how do i get it back?

Tags: intellij-idea

I use Inteliji IDEA for a scala project and this has some external library ,say x
it has x-2.00 and x-2.02 , i deleted x-2.02  mistakenly , now how do i get this back ?
OS : MAC

Answer (score 0):

Every change you make is stored locally by IntelliJ in the "Local History". See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/local-history.html for more info.

In short: simply right click in the project explorer and click "local history" -> "show history" and you can view all your actions and undo/redo them.

Note: no need to have version control enabled. Also very usefull if you have VCS enabled because it adds a more granular level of history.